# Pasar como parámetro a una función una fórmula y una tabla donde está incluida para que la calcule y devuelva. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, function, funcion, innodb

Agradezco de antemano a la comunidad por el tiempo dedicado a la consulta.

Tengo una tabla donde almaceno, además de otras cosas, una fórmula entre campos y la tabla donde están dichos propios campos. Imaginemos una cosa así:

Campo: formula |  Valor: SUM(pedidos) + SUM(ventas) |||
Campo: tabla_calculo | Valor: transacciones

Lo que estaba buscando hacer es lo siguiente: Creo una función a la que le paso como parámetro la fórmula y la tabla donde están los campos y me devuelve el resultado del cálculo en Decimal. Lo que tengo hecho es:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calcular (calculo varchar(100), tabla_calculo varchar(100), mes int(2), anio int(4), idempleado int(6))
 RETURNS DECIMAL

BEGIN

SELECT calculo INTO @N
FROM tabla_calculo
WHERE MONTH(fecha) =  mes
AND YEAR(fecha)= anio
AND id_empleado = idempleado
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha), YEAR(fecha), id_empleado;

Return @N;   

END
```

Y la invocaría más o menos así:

SELECT calcular('SUM(pedidos) + SUM(ventas)', 'transacciones', '06', '2022', '909090').

Y está pensada para invocarla dentro de un Select global, que luego os detallo.

Ahora os cuento lo que funciona y no funciona:

- Si ejecuto la función con el comando "ejecutar" del propio Phpmyadmin y meto estos parámetros sin comillas por pantalla -> Funciona (o dice que lo hace porque no hay eco en pantalla, claro, al solo retornar un decimal "al aire").
- Si la llamo desde fuera con el "Select" -> No funciona. No termina de "resolver" el nombre del cálculo y la tabla. Intenta buscar una tabla que se llama "tabla_calculo", que realmente es el nombre del parámetro.
- Si solo dejo los parámetros de año, mes e ID de empleado y le digo explícitamente tabla y cálculo dentro de la función -> Funciona (pero no puedo hacerlo porque son bastantes tablas e innumerables cálculos).

Sé que hay una alternativa, que es crear un Procedure y componer una sentencia Select, pero es una solución que no me vale, porque lo que realmente quisiera hacer, sería hacer un Select global más o menos así:

SELECT IDempleado, mes, anio, calcular('pedidos + ventas', 'tabla_campos', mes, anio, IDempleado)

De forma que de una sentada pudiera sacar el empleado, el período y el cálculo. Lo simplifico mucho para no liar algún más, pero el empleado está en varios departamentos, por lo que necesito cálculos parciales y ésta es la única manera de sacar todo el rendimiento por empleado de una sentada. No me vale el Procedure porque no puedo invocarlo por cada registro del Select. Tendría que andar haciendo una especie de Array donde metiera cada fila que tenga datos, luego recorrerlo (a lo mejor desde otro procedimiento)... Y solo en rendimiento ya sería un desastre.

¿A alguien se le ocurre algo para resolverlo con una función que es más simple que un tebeo? La idea es que pueda pasarle como parámetro la tabla y el cálculo, que están almacenados como campos en otra tabla, y lo entienda y ejecute.

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO español, te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed), ahora en cuanto tu problema en la función devuelves un decimal y calculo por lo que pones en el código es varchar por lo que es incompatible, mira eso y luego nos comenta, también si es posible añadir a tu pregunta la tabla calculo seria de gran ayuda. Saludos :-)

Comment: No se puede. No puedes invocar SQL dinámico desde una función. Tendrás que resolverlo en otra capa de tu aplicación.